# ion-select make big round shade

Tags: sass, ionic3, ion-select

working with ionic3, when I add an  tag, it make a big shadow on almost all screen... I do not find any property  on css that have any effect on it...

here a screen shot:[image]

```
        <div class="clockselect">
      <label>Type:</label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="alarm.type" style="font-size: 20px">
        <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="Thuesday">Thuesday</option>
        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
        <option value="Weekend">Weekend</option>
        <option value="All days">All days</option>
      </select>
      <span class="clockZone">
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="alarm.hour">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let Hour of hours">{{Hour}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
        <h3>:</h3>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="alarm.minute">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let Min of mins">{{Min}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </span>
    </div>
```

css:

```
           .clockZone {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            width: 140px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: rgb(240, 246, 255);
            border-radius: 6px;

            ion-select {
                width: 65px;
                box-shadow: transparent;
                align-items: center;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in that forum:
[Ion-select triggering on whole-view..(activating on click anywhere)](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-select-triggering-on-whole-view-activating-on-click-anywhere/86772/2)

I just have to add in scss page's file:

```
.item-cover {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```